# Optimise a POSTGRESQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE true, COSTS true, FORMAT json) 
SELECT ORDER0_.C_ORDER_ID AS C_ORDER_1_244_
--- OTHER COLUMNS ---
FROM C_ORDER ORDER0_
CROSS JOIN OBPOS_APP_CASHUP OBPOS_APP_1_
WHERE ORDER0_.AD_ORG_ID = '4393B956D34E49D782CA0AA448629515'
    AND OBPOS_APP_1_.OBPOS_APP_CASHUP_ID = ORDER0_.EM_OBPOS_APP_CASHUP_ID
    AND OBPOS_APP_1_.CASHUPDATE <= 'Fri Jun 23 00:00:00 CEST 2023'
    AND (ORDER0_.C_ORDER_ID IN
                            (SELECT ORDER4_.C_ORDER_ID
                                FROM M_INOUTLINE MATERIALMG2_
                                INNER JOIN M_INOUT MATERIALMG3_ ON MATERIALMG2_.M_INOUT_ID = MATERIALMG3_.M_INOUT_ID
                                INNER JOIN C_ORDER ORDER4_ ON MATERIALMG3_.C_ORDER_ID = ORDER4_.C_ORDER_ID
                                WHERE MATERIALMG3_.MOVEMENTDATE >= 'Fri Jun 23 00:00:00 CEST 2023'
                                    AND MATERIALMG3_.MOVEMENTDATE < 'Fri Jun 24 00:00:00 CEST 2023'
                                GROUP BY ORDER4_.C_ORDER_ID
                                HAVING COALESCE(SUM(MATERIALMG2_.MOVEMENTQTY),

                                                                0) > 0))
    AND (ORDER0_.C_ORDER_ID NOT IN
                            (SELECT ORDER5_.C_ORDER_ID
                                FROM C_ORDER ORDER5_
                                CROSS JOIN OBPOS_APP_CASHUP OBPOS_APP_6_
                                INNER JOIN AD_ORG ORGANIZATI7_ ON OBPOS_APP_6_.AD_ORG_ID = ORGANIZATI7_.AD_ORG_ID
                                WHERE OBPOS_APP_6_.OBPOS_APP_CASHUP_ID = ORDER5_.EM_OBPOS_APP_CASHUP_ID
                                    AND OBPOS_APP_6_.ISPROCESSED = 'Y'
                                    AND TRUNC(OBPOS_APP_6_.CASHUPDATE) = 'Fri Jun 23 00:00:00 CEST 2023'
                                    AND ORGANIZATI7_.AD_ORG_ID = '4393B956D34E49D782CA0AA448629515'
                                    AND ORGANIZATI7_.EM_OBWESA_TYPE = 'RETAIL'));
```

With the following explain results:

```
#   Node    Timings     Rows            Loops   
        Exclusive   Inclusive   Rows X  Actual  Plan        
    1   Nested Loop Inner Join (cost=16011892.59..16521927.99 rows=1625 width=5056) (actual=1738176.172..1738176.18 rows=0 loops=1) 0.001 ms    1738176.18 ms   ↓ 1 0   1625    1
    2   Hash Inner Join (cost=16011892.17..16518678.14 rows=1829 width=5056) (actual=1738176.171..1738176.179 rows=0 loops=1)Hash Cond: ((order0_.c_order_id)::text = (order4_.c_order_id)::text)   1195.671 ms 1738176.179 ms  ↓ 1 0   1829    1
    3   "Bitmap Heap Scan on c_order as order0_ (cost=5236.11..322736.22 rows=150044 width=5056) (actual=4110.816..51254.322 rows=296921 loops=1)Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
Rows Removed by Filter: 432
Recheck Cond: ((ad_org_id)::text = '4393B956D34E49D782CA0AA448629515'::text)
Heap Blocks: exact=64186"   47163.579 ms    51254.322 ms    ↓ 1.98  296921  150044  1
    4   Bitmap Index Scan using c_order_id (cost=0..4964.91 rows=300087 width=0) (actual=3818.477..3818.477 rows=297355 loops=1)Index Cond: ((ad_org_id)::text = '4393B956D34E49D782CA0AA448629515'::text)  3818.477 ms 3818.477 ms ↑ 1.01  297355  300087  1
    5   Nested Loop Inner Join (cost=24.81..233.55 rows=54 width=33) (actual=38.389..272.266 rows=432 loops=1)  124.347 ms  272.266 ms  ↓ 8 432 54  1
    6   Nested Loop Inner Join (cost=24.25..27.84 rows=1 width=33) (actual=23.612..23.625 rows=2 loops=1)   0.013 ms    23.625 ms   ↓ 2 2   1   1
    7   "Bitmap Heap Scan on obpos_app_cashup as obpos_app_6_ (cost=23.97..25.34 rows=1 width=66) (actual=23.597..23.602 rows=2 loops=1)Filter: (isprocessed = 'Y'::bpchar)
Rows Removed by Filter: 0
Recheck Cond: ((trunc(cashupdate) = '2023-06-23'::date) AND ((ad_org_id)::text = '4393B956D34E49D782CA0AA448629515'::text))
Heap Blocks: exact=1"   0.013 ms    23.602 ms   ↓ 2 2   1   1
    8   Bitmap AND (cost=23.97..23.97 rows=1 width=0) (actual=23.589..23.59 rows=0 loops=1) 0.036 ms    23.59 ms    ↓ 1 0   1   1
    9   Bitmap Index Scan using obpos_app_cashup_date_idx (cost=0..6.67 rows=540 width=0) (actual=12.28..12.28 rows=1055 loops=1)Index Cond: (trunc(cashupdate) = '2023-06-23'::date)   12.28 ms    12.28 ms    ↓ 1.96  1055    540 1
    10  Bitmap Index Scan using obpos_app_cashup_org (cost=0..17.05 rows=1043 width=0) (actual=11.275..11.275 rows=1727 loops=1)Index Cond: ((ad_org_id)::text = '4393B956D34E49D782CA0AA448629515'::text)  11.275 ms   11.275 ms   ↓ 1.66  1727    1043    1
    11  "Index Scan using ad_org_key on ad_org as organizati7_ (cost=0.27..2.49 rows=1 width=32) (actual=0.009..0.01 rows=1 loops=2)Filter: ((em_obwesa_type)::text = 'RETAIL'::text)
Index Cond: ((ad_org_id)::text = '4393B956D34E49D782CA0AA448629515'::text)
Rows Removed by Filter: 0"  0.01 ms 0.01 ms ↑ 1 1   1   2
    12  Index Scan using em_obpos_app_cashup_idx on c_order as order5_ (cost=0.56..203.91 rows=180 width=65) (actual=14.278..124.295 rows=216 loops=2)Index Cond: ((em_obpos_app_cashup_id)::text = (obpos_app_6_.obpos_app_cashup_id)::text)   124.295 ms  124.295 ms  ↓ 1.2   216 180 2
    13  Hash (cost=15999371.91..15999371.91 rows=358572 width=33) (actual=1685726.184..1685726.187 rows=67950 loops=1)Buckets: 131072 Batches: 8 Memory Usage: 1563 kB  16.203 ms   1685726.187 ms  ↑ 5.28  67950   358572  1
    14  "Aggregate (cost=15988614.75..15995786.19 rows=358572 width=33) (actual=1685609.313..1685709.984 rows=67950 loops=1)Filter: (COALESCE(sum(materialmg2_.movementqty), '0'::numeric) > '0'::numeric)
Rows Removed by Filter: 2483"   53.769 ms   1685709.984 ms  ↑ 5.28  67950   358572  1
    15  Sort (cost=15988614.75..15989511.18 rows=358572 width=38) (actual=1685609.301..1685656.215 rows=172319 loops=1) 368.361 ms  1685656.215 ms  ↑ 2.09  172319  358572  1
    16  Hash Inner Join (cost=9823288.47..15949788.97 rows=358572 width=38) (actual=822018.009..1685287.855 rows=172319 loops=1)Hash Cond: ((materialmg2_.m_inout_id)::text = (materialmg3_.m_inout_id)::text)  41744.298 ms    1685287.855 ms  ↑ 2.09  172319  358572  1
    17  Seq Scan on m_inoutline as materialmg2_ (cost=0..4731797.84 rows=71714384 width=38) (actual=3.718..875075.605 rows=71714388 loops=1)    875075.605 ms   875075.605 ms   ↓ 1.01  71714388    71714384    1
    18  Hash (cost=9819879.08..9819879.08 rows=140751 width=66) (actual=768467.95..768467.952 rows=70433 loops=1)Buckets: 65536 Batches: 4 Memory Usage: 2198 kB    83.283 ms   768467.952 ms   ↑ 2 70433   140751  1
    19  Nested Loop Inner Join (cost=0.56..9819879.08 rows=140751 width=66) (actual=262310.864..768384.67 rows=70433 loops=1)   283240.752 ms   768384.67 ms    ↑ 2 70433   140751  1
    20  "Seq Scan on m_inout as materialmg3_ (cost=0..9583058.8 rows=140751 width=66) (actual=262300.7..485139.899 rows=70433 loops=1)Filter: (trunc(movementdate) = '2023-06-23'::date)
Rows Removed by Filter: 28079796"   485139.899 ms   485139.899 ms   ↑ 2 70433   140751  1
    21  Index Only Scan using c_order_key on c_order as order4_ (cost=0.56..1.68 rows=1 width=33) (actual=4.02..4.02 rows=1 loops=70433)Index Cond: (c_order_id = (materialmg3_.c_order_id)::text)  4.02 ms 4.02 ms ↑ 1 1   1   70433
    22  "Index Scan using obpos_appcash_pk on obpos_app_cashup as obpos_app_1_ (cost=0.42..1.78 rows=1 width=33) (actual=0..0 rows=0 loops=0)Filter: (cashupdate <= '2023-06-23 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
Index Cond: ((obpos_app_cashup_id)::text = (order0_.em_obpos_app_cashup_id)::text)
Rows Removed by Filter: 0"  1 ms    1 ms    ↓ 1 0   1   0
                                
Total rows: 1 of 1                              
Query complete 00:29:02.257
```

I have optimised it by adjusting the query to the following

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE true, COSTS true, FORMAT json)
SELECT ORDER0_.C_ORDER_ID AS C_ORDER_1_244_
--- OTHER COLUMNS ---
FROM C_ORDER ORDER0_
CROSS JOIN OBPOS_APP_CASHUP OBPOS_APP_1_
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ORDER4_.C_ORDER_ID
    FROM M_INOUTLINE MATERIALMG2_
    INNER JOIN M_INOUT MATERIALMG3_ ON MATERIALMG2_.M_INOUT_ID = MATERIALMG3_.M_INOUT_ID
    INNER JOIN C_ORDER ORDER4_ ON MATERIALMG3_.C_ORDER_ID = ORDER4_.C_ORDER_ID
    WHERE MATERIALMG3_.MOVEMENTDATE >= 'Fri Jun 23 00:00:00 CEST 2023'
        AND MATERIALMG3_.MOVEMENTDATE < 'Fri Jun 24 00:00:00 CEST 2023'
    GROUP BY ORDER4_.C_ORDER_ID
    HAVING COALESCE(SUM(MATERIALMG2_.MOVEMENTQTY), 0) > 0
) AS SUBQ1 ON ORDER0_.C_ORDER_ID = SUBQ1.C_ORDER_ID

-- Replacing NOT IN with LEFT JOIN
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ORDER5_.C_ORDER_ID
    FROM C_ORDER ORDER5_
    CROSS JOIN OBPOS_APP_CASHUP OBPOS_APP_6_
    INNER JOIN AD_ORG ORGANIZATI7_ ON OBPOS_APP_6_.AD_ORG_ID = ORGANIZATI7_.AD_ORG_ID
    WHERE OBPOS_APP_6_.OBPOS_APP_CASHUP_ID = ORDER5_.EM_OBPOS_APP_CASHUP_ID
        AND OBPOS_APP_6_.ISPROCESSED = 'Y'
        AND TRUNC(OBPOS_APP_6_.CASHUPDATE) = 'Fri Jun 23 00:00:00 CEST 2023'
        AND ORGANIZATI7_.AD_ORG_ID = '4393B956D34E49D782CA0AA448629515'
        AND ORGANIZATI7_.EM_OBWESA_TYPE = 'RETAIL'
) AS SUBQ2 ON ORDER0_.C_ORDER_ID = SUBQ2.C_ORDER_ID

WHERE ORDER0_.AD_ORG_ID = '4393B956D34E49D782CA0AA448629515'
    AND OBPOS_APP_1_.OBPOS_APP_CASHUP_ID = ORDER0_.EM_OBPOS_APP_CASHUP_ID
    AND OBPOS_APP_1_.CASHUPDATE <= 'Fri Jun 23 00:00:00 CEST 2023'
    AND SUBQ2.C_ORDER_ID IS NULL;  -- This line ensures we only get rows that didn't have a match in the LEFT JOIN, equivalent to the NOT IN condition.
```

The new explain is:

```
#   Node    Timings     Rows            Loops   
        Exclusive   Inclusive   Rows X  Actual  Plan        
    1   Merge Anti Join (cost=5069936.34..5262682.02 rows=665 width=5059) (actual=684433.17..684433.175 rows=0 loops=1) 0.003 ms    684433.175 ms   ↓ 1 0   665 1
    2   Nested Loop Inner Join (cost=5069697.88..5262441.63 rows=665 width=5059) (actual=684433.169..684433.173 rows=0 loops=1) 16.083 ms   684433.173 ms   ↓ 1 0   665 1
    3   Nested Loop Inner Join (cost=5069697.46..5260790.33 rows=750 width=5059) (actual=652042.538..684417.052 rows=413 loops=1)   33409.011 ms    684417.052 ms   ↑ 1.82  413 750 1
    4   Unique (cost=5069696.9..5071299.1 rows=71209 width=33) (actual=650894.947..651007.551 rows=67950 loops=1)   12.923 ms   651007.551 ms   ↑ 1.05  67950   71209   1
    5   "Aggregate (cost=5069696.9..5071121.08 rows=71209 width=33) (actual=650894.946..650994.629 rows=67950 loops=1)Filter: (COALESCE(sum(materialmg2_.movementqty), '0'::numeric) > '0'::numeric)
Rows Removed by Filter: 2483"   69.623 ms   650994.629 ms   ↑ 1.05  67950   71209   1
    6   Sort (cost=5069696.9..5069874.92 rows=71209 width=38) (actual=650894.931..650925.006 rows=172319 loops=1)   258.872 ms  650925.006 ms   ↓ 2.42  172319  71209   1
    7   Nested Loop Inner Join (cost=16654.11..5063957.53 rows=71209 width=38) (actual=937.917..650666.135 rows=172319 loops=1) 898.982 ms  650666.135 ms   ↓ 2.42  172319  71209   1
    8   Hash Inner Join (cost=16653.54..4936701.35 rows=71209 width=38) (actual=937.883..649767.149 rows=172319 loops=1)Hash Cond: ((materialmg2_.m_inout_id)::text = (materialmg3_.m_inout_id)::text)  14691.437 ms    649767.149 ms   ↓ 2.42  172319  71209   1
    9   Seq Scan on m_inoutline as materialmg2_ (cost=0..4731798 rows=71714200 width=38) (actual=0.005..634975.233 rows=71714425 loops=1)   634975.233 ms   634975.233 ms   ↓ 1.01  71714425    71714200    1
    10  Hash (cost=16304.14..16304.14 rows=27952 width=66) (actual=100.478..100.479 rows=70433 loops=1)Buckets: 131072 Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 7765 kB 20.621 ms   100.479 ms  ↓ 2.52  70433   27952   1
    11  Index Scan using m_inout_movementdate_id on m_inout as materialmg3_ (cost=0.56..16304.14 rows=27952 width=66) (actual=0.015..79.859 rows=70433 loops=1)Index Cond: ((movementdate >= '2023-06-23 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (movementdate < '2023-06-24 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))   79.859 ms   79.859 ms   ↓ 2.52  70433   27952   1
    12  Index Only Scan using c_order_key on c_order as order4_ (cost=0.56..1.79 rows=1 width=33) (actual=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=172319)Index Cond: (c_order_id = (materialmg3_.c_order_id)::text)   0.005 ms    0.005 ms    ↑ 1 1   1   172319
    13  "Index Scan using c_order_key on c_order as order0_ (cost=0.56..2.65 rows=1 width=5059) (actual=0.491..0.491 rows=0 loops=67950)Filter: ((ad_org_id)::text = '4393B956D34E49D782CA0AA448629515'::text)
Index Cond: ((c_order_id)::text = (order4_.c_order_id)::text)
Rows Removed by Filter: 1"  0.491 ms    0.491 ms    ↓ 1 0   1   67950
    14  "Index Scan using obpos_appcash_pk on obpos_app_cashup as obpos_app_1_ (cost=0.42..2.2 rows=1 width=33) (actual=0.038..0.038 rows=0 loops=413)Filter: (cashupdate <= '2023-06-23 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
Index Cond: ((obpos_app_cashup_id)::text = (order0_.em_obpos_app_cashup_id)::text)
Rows Removed by Filter: 1"  0.038 ms    0.038 ms    ↓ 1 0   1   413
    15  Sort (cost=238.45..238.59 rows=54 width=33) (actual=0..0 rows=0 loops=0)    0   0   ↓ 1 0   54  0
    16  Nested Loop Inner Join (cost=24.77..236.9 rows=54 width=33) (actual=0..0 rows=0 loops=0)    0   0   ↓ 1 0   54  0
    17  Nested Loop Inner Join (cost=24.21..27.81 rows=1 width=33) (actual=0..0 rows=0 loops=0) 0   0   ↓ 1 0   1   0
    18  "Bitmap Heap Scan on obpos_app_cashup as obpos_app_6_ (cost=23.94..25.3 rows=1 width=66) (actual=0..0 rows=0 loops=0)Filter: (isprocessed = 'Y'::bpchar)
Rows Removed by Filter: 0
Recheck Cond: ((trunc(cashupdate) = '2023-06-23'::date) AND ((ad_org_id)::text = '4393B956D34E49D782CA0AA448629515'::text))
Heap Blocks: exact=0"   0   0   ↓ 1 0   1   0
    19  Bitmap AND (cost=23.94..23.94 rows=1 width=0) (actual=0..0 rows=0 loops=0)  0   0   ↓ 1 0   1   0
    20  Bitmap Index Scan using obpos_app_cashup_date_idx (cost=0..6.6 rows=530 width=0) (actual=0..0 rows=0 loops=0)Index Cond: (trunc(cashupdate) = '2023-06-23'::date)   1 ms    1 ms    ↓ 1 0   530 0
    21  Bitmap Index Scan using obpos_app_cashup_org (cost=0..17.09 rows=1048 width=0) (actual=0..0 rows=0 loops=0)Index Cond: ((ad_org_id)::text = '4393B956D34E49D782CA0AA448629515'::text)   1 ms    1 ms    ↓ 1 0   1048    0
    22  "Index Scan using ad_org_key on ad_org as organizati7_ (cost=0.27..2.49 rows=1 width=32) (actual=0..0 rows=0 loops=0)Filter: ((em_obwesa_type)::text = 'RETAIL'::text)
Index Cond: ((ad_org_id)::text = '4393B956D34E49D782CA0AA448629515'::text)
Rows Removed by Filter: 0"  1 ms    1 ms    ↓ 1 0   1   0
    23  Index Scan using em_obpos_app_cashup_idx on c_order as order5_ (cost=0.56..207.26 rows=183 width=65) (actual=0..0 rows=0 loops=0)Index Cond: ((em_obpos_app_cashup_id)::text = (obpos_app_6_.obpos_app_cashup_id)::text)    1 ms    1 ms    ↓ 1 0   183 0
Total rows: 1 of 1
```

The only indices I can think of adding already exist.

THe new version of the query has just moved the sequential search further up in the perfromance plan from row 18 to row 9.

I am at a loss for ideas on how to improve.

Does anyone have any suggestions without me having to give away the schemas to the tables?

Comment: Those plans are unreadable.  It looks like they were scraped from depesz but lost the formatting.  Please either link to the plans on depesz, or paste the raw text-format plans formatted as code, so as to preserve indents.